# Can I use the result of a C++17 captureless lambda constexpr conversion operator as a function pointer template non-type argument?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, language-lawyer, c++17

While answering [How do I write a lambda expression that looks like a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604606/how-do-i-write-a-lambda-expression-that-looks-like-a-method), I tried to turn a captureless lambda into a member function pointer by exploiting the fact that, since C++17, captureless lambdas have a **constexpr** conversion operator to their function pointer type.

So I came up with an issue boiling down to:

```
template<void(*)()> struct A{};

int main()
{
  A<static_cast<void(*)()>([]{})>{}; // 1

  constexpr auto fp = static_cast<void(*)()>([]{});
  A<fp>{}; // 2
}
```

Now, this compiles in clang (since 5.0.0) but gcc(>=7.2) complains:

```
error: lambda-expression in template-argument
   A<static_cast<void(*)()>([]{ /*whatever*/ })>{}; // 1
                            ^
error: 'main()::<lambda()>::_FUN' is not a valid template argument for type 'void (*)()' because 'static constexpr void main()::<lambda()>::_FUN()' has no linkage
   A<fp>{}; // 2
```

The question is, **who's right?**

Comment: A simpler example using constexpr local variables should exist, no?

Comment: @Yakk, done;  this is not entirely equivalent to the original code though ... or not ?

Comment: I cannot help wondering what you are trying to do exactly and why this is needed.

Comment: @germandiago this is a language lawyer question... why one would use it is irrilevant. Anyway, the ability of portably casting a lambda to, say, a member pointer may have use cases I think ...

Comment: Pointer to function with no linkage should be allowed to be a non-type template argument in C++17. See [N4198](http://wg21.link/N4198).

Comment: @cpplearner ah I see, so clang's right; may you write an answer ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes: So you should write a bug report! ;)

Comment: @massim not quite the same, but 3 times simpler.  And I can see the use; fastest possible delegates the portable version.

Comment: @Klaus, indeed the [gcc standards support page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) claims support for [n4268](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html) (AFAIK formerly known as N4198), so I'll file a bug report (unless anybody else has something to say ) ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a gcc bug, filed [83258](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83258).

In C++14, we used to have a [linkage requirement](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.arg.nontype#1.3) for non-type template parameters of pointer type. But in C++17 (as a result of [N4268](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html)), the parameter just needs to be a [converted constant expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#2) of the correct type, with a few other restrictions (none of which are relevant here). Once we can construct `fp`, we should be able to use it as a template parameter.